# Creating a 3x3 grid with auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, autolayout

Xcode has said there are no layout issues but as you can see there is. I have tried everything. Apple docs, YouTube, Google, etc. It seems I am doing it right however maybe the order I'm doing things in or something else is causing these issues. After trying everything I finally let Xcode `add missing constraints` and it's the best result so far. I have 9 buttons onto of 9 UIImages so I have to do the same thing I do to the buttons as I do with the UIImages. I have temporarily placed the UIImages on top of the buttons so I can see what I'm doing more easily. I've got 2 screenshots. Please advise.

Beginning

[image: Beginning]

This is after using Xcode's `add missing constraints` option. 
Sorta what I want but no cigar.

[image]

Answer (score 58, accepted):

#### iOS 9 or later

If your deployment target is iOS 9 or later, there is a simpler solution using `UIStackView`. Please see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415807/77567).

#### iOS 8 or earlier

There are a number of ways you could create this layout with constraints. Here's one.

First, a tip: you can name your views in the document outline. This makes it much easier to understand which views are which and what your constraints are connected to. To name a view, click it in the outline, press return, and type the name.  Then the outline can look like this:

[image: outline with names]

If you change the names, you may need to close the file (menu bar > File > Close “Main.storyboard”) and reopen it to make everything update properly.

(Note that these names are only used when editing the storyboard.  There is no way to get these names at runtime.)

OK, now to create the constraints. Start by constraining all the left-right edges to nearest neighbor with constant value zero:

[image: left-right constraints]

Next, constrain the top and bottom edges of the top row to nearest neighbor with constant value zero. If you want to constrain to the top edge of the superview, rather than to the top layout guide, you have to do them one by one. Here's how to do the first one:

[image: top-bottom constraints of top-left]

Repeat for the other two views in the top row.

Next, constrain the top and bottom edges of the bottom row to nearest neighbor with constant value zero. Again, if you want to constrain to the bottom edge of the superview, you have to do them one at a time.  Example:

[image: top-bottom constraints of bottom-left]

Repeat for the other two views in the bottom row.

Note that you **don't** have to create top-bottom constraints for the middle row, because the top and bottom rows are now constrained to the middle row.

Finally, select all your views and create equal-width and equal-height constraints:

[image: equal width and height constraints]

Check out the result using Preview in the Assistant editor:

[image: preview]

If you forget any constraints, the document outline will show a red arrow at the top right. Click it for some help identifying what's missing. For example, if you forget to add the top and bottom constraints to the top-center view, you get an error like this:

[image: missing constraints error]

Comment: Wow Rob. Thanks soo much. It's quite a lot to digest so I'll study it all today and let you know how it goes. I was going to post this updated screenshot as you can see with my space tic tac toe.  I will start all over again and go by your tutorial. In the meantime what do you think of my layout? I don't have any errors and they are all aligned. Unfortunately the sizes and positions don't adjust to 5.5". Talk to you in a bit. p.s. you even gave me a gif. That's great. Really appreciate it. Are you more of a designer, programmer or both?                            http://i.imgur.com/xlahfUk.jpg

Comment: Btw, with the background image I think I'm setting too many things. Since it's just a BG do I just set these four options?         http://i.imgur.com/VQxb417.png

Comment: And you said "If you want to constrain to the top edge of the superview, rather than to the top layout guide, you have to do them one by one." Since I have a navigator what do you recommend? top edge of superview or layout guide?

Comment: Thanks to you Rob it's looking good. I realized I was using way too many constraints. http://i.imgur.com/paFKjfW.jpg       Just some tweaks needed. I think I'm getting all those warnings because I set all 3 in the the top row at the same time. I'm not sure if I was to do it one by one since I didn't know the difference between superview and top layout guide so I went ahead and set all 3 at the same time. I'm using a navigator so maybe that's why things went astray? Also I'd like the X's in the 5.5" layout to be smaller since they look so huge. How would I control that? Thanks

Comment: Rob!!!! Success!!! I simply forgot to click Update Constraints for all the X's. I did exactly as you said and waited to click update constraints until the end because some people were saying it's better to do that. Only one tiny issue. The X's are cut off on all edges. Why would this happen? Can this be fixed or should I start over? Here's my new nice screen thanks to you :)         http://i.imgur.com/Ogr2UA1.jpg

Comment: Interesting. I tested on my 6+ instead and got acceptable results. http://i.imgur.com/PvpLq9i.jpg   I would like the X's to be a but smaller and there seems to be left and right white margins on my phone. What should I do? Why would my actual 6+ look different than Xcode's 5.5" preview? Is that why they always say to test using Skala etc? p.s. you cannot see my white margins on the white imgur page but if you look below the navigator you can see the margin difference.

Comment: uploaded a new screen so you can see the margins I want to  get rid of.http://i.imgur.com/XZ7E6Hy.jpg

Comment: What I did to test is I selected the View in the Document outline and changed the bg to green to see if I could source the problem. As you can see my black space bg is not covering it all so I'm wondering how to fix it without ruining my layout? http://i.imgur.com/bVJgbFX.png?1

Comment: Here are my measurements and story board. I tried changing some constraints but of course that starts getting scary lol I just kept getting warnings. My app's bg is the "grid" in the document outline. http://i.imgur.com/DV10VQh.jpg

Comment: What is the View mode for each of your image views (including the background view)?  E.g. “Scale To Fill”, “Aspect Fill”, “Aspect Fit”'.

Comment: The view and bg are both set to scale to fill. I changed it around but no luck.   Here are 2 screens.  http://i.imgur.com/nWJTld2.png      |  http://i.imgur.com/OsH7GVF.png

Comment: Really appreciate the amount of detail that has gone into this!

Comment: I always wonder why I get the missing x and y xonstraints. I used to give all the 4 constraints to each element in my IB. This answer taught me well!!!!

Comment: ha ha, you went 'all in' on the GIF's!

Answer (score 55):

**If you're targeting iOS 9 or later,** you can make a grid of any dimensions much more easily using stack views. Make one horizontal stack view for each row, and then put all the horizontal stack views in a single vertical stack view. Set the Distribution of all of the stack views (both horizontal and vertical) to Fill Equally. Then set constraints on the vertical stack view to control the overall size of the grid.

Here's a demo. I'll start with nine image views:

[image: nine image views]

First I'll create three horizontal stack views, one for each row of the grid. Since I've already manually arranged the image views in a rough grid shape, Xcode is smart enough to use horizontal stack views automatically:

[image: horizontal stack views for rows]

Next I'll select the three horizontal stack views and set the Distribution of all three to Fill Equally at the same time:

[image: setting the distribution of row stacks]

Now I'll put all of the horizontal stack views into one vertical stack view, and set the vertical stack view's Distribution to Fill Equally. Again, since the horizontal stack views are already laid out roughly vertically, Xcode is smart enough to use a vertical stack view automatically:

[image: vertical stack view]

Finally, I'll put constraints on the vertical stack view to make it fill its container (except for the status bar area). Then I'll tell Xcode to update the frames of all the views, and I'll have a perfect 3x3 grid with hardly any work:

[image: constraints on the vertical stack view]

Comment: I just fell in love with UIStackView

Comment: Ha ha yeah, it really puts autolayout on autopilot.

Comment: Amazing and fabulous! This was something I needed from long! Great job!

Comment: Hey, is there a way you can do this for buttons to make a tic tac toe grid? I tried following, but the size of the buttons just goes back to default.

Comment: @robmayoff - fantastic visual explanation! If a picture is worth a 1000 words, a short animation (and not a huge video) is worth a short novel!