# NSLayoutConstraint for unknown number of subviews in code

Tags: ios

I'm getting into iOS programming and mastered more or less autolayout with fixed number of items. Say, we have a UILabel for title, UILabel for subtitle, then the visual format for the constraint is `'V:|-[title]-10-[subtitle]-|'`

But what if I create subviews dynamically based on some API response. There are for example 40 subviews I need to add. It's not realistic anymore that I specify each subview with the visual format and keep track of them. What is the the proper way?

I imagine that after each subview I add, I then set the constraint based on the previous view with `constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:`. Is that the way to go, or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not realistic anymore that I specify each subview with the visual format and keep track of them

Why on earth not? You seem to think this is some sort of "either/or" situation. Nothing prevents you from using visual formatting to build up a collection of constraints. No law says that you have to put *all* your constraints into *one* visual format.

And the layout engine doesn't know or care what *notation* you used to form your constraints. A constraint is a constraint!

Consider this code where I build up the constraints for a scroll view and thirty labels inside it:

```
    var con = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
    con.appendContentsOf(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "H:|[sv]|",
            options:[], metrics:nil,
            views:["sv":sv]))
    con.appendContentsOf(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:|[sv]|",
            options:[], metrics:nil,
            views:["sv":sv]))
    var previousLab : UILabel? = nil
    for i in 0 ..< 30 {
        let lab = UILabel()
        // lab.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        lab.text = "This is label \(i+1)"
        sv.addSubview(lab)
        con.appendContentsOf(
            NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                "H:|-(10)-[lab]",
                options:[], metrics:nil,
                views:["lab":lab]))
        if previousLab == nil { // first one, pin to top
            con.appendContentsOf(
                NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                    "V:|-(10)-[lab]",
                    options:[], metrics:nil,
                    views:["lab":lab]))
        } else { // all others, pin to previous
            con.appendContentsOf(
                NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
                    "V:[prev]-(10)-[lab]",
                    options:[], metrics:nil,
                    views:["lab":lab, "prev":previousLab!]))
        }
        previousLab = lab
    }
    con.appendContentsOf(
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(
            "V:[lab]-(10)-|",
            options:[], metrics:nil,
            views:["lab":previousLab!]))
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(con)
```

I'm using visual formatting, but I'm doing it one constraint as a time as I add views (which is exactly what you're asking about).

Comment: Ha. Now I feel kind of dumb :) Thanks

Comment: Note that you'll also need to constrain the last label to the bottom of the scroll view if you want the scroll view to set its `contentSize.height` to actually allow scrolling.

Comment: @robmayoff did that, just got cut off when pasting

Answer (score 0):

The answer really depends on what layout you want, because there are higher-level tools for making some layouts.

Starting with iOS 9, you can use `UIStackView` to manage a row or column of views. [By nesting stack views, you can easily make a grid of views.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36415807/77567) For an introduction to `UIStackView`, start by watching [“Mysteries of Auto Layout, Part 1” from WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/218/). If you're doing all your layout in code, you can use [`TZStackView`](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView), a reimplementation of `UIStackView` that works on iOS 7 and later.

`UICollectionView` is another tool for laying out views in a grid, or in many other arrangements. It's more complex than `UIStackView`, but there's a lot of introductory material available to teach you how to use it, such as [“Introducing Collection Views” from WWDC 2012](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012/205/).

Answer (score 0):

I built a dynamic layout engine (Horizontal layout and Vertical layout).

1. It accepts an array of views.
2. It adds the views as subviews to a container.
3. Then composes a vertical and horizontal Visual layout string dynamically.  (It generates a unique "Object Address" string for each view being laid out using v%p.
4. Simply call: [myView addControls:@[view1, view2, view3]] in viewDidLoad, and it will lay them out vertically for you.
5. Here's a generic layout engine for a vertical layout.   Enjoy.

   ```
   @implementation UIView (VerticalLayout)

   - (void)addControls:(NSArray*)controls
       align:(VerticalAlignment)alignment
       withHeight:(CGFloat)height
       verticalPadding:(CGFloat)verticalPadding
       horizontalPadding:(CGFloat)horizontalPadding
       topPadding:(CGFloat)topPadding
       bottomPadding:(CGFloat)bottomPadding
       withWidth:(CGFloat)width
   {
       NSMutableDictionary* bindings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
       NSDictionary *metrics = @{
           @"topPadding": @(topPadding),
           @"bottomPadding": @(bottomPadding),
           @"verticalPadding": @(verticalPadding),
           @"horizontalPadding":@(horizontalPadding) };

       NSMutableString* verticalConstraint = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"V:"];
       if (alignment == VerticalAlignTop || alignment == VerticalAlignStretchToFullHeight) {
           [verticalConstraint appendString:@"|"];
       }

       for (UIView* view in controls) {
           BOOL isFirstView = [controls firstObject] == view;
           BOOL isLastView = [controls lastObject] == view;

           [self addSubview: view];

           // Add to vertical constraint string
           NSString* viewName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%p",view];
           [bindings setObject:view forKey:viewName];

           NSString* yLeadingPaddingString = @"";
           NSString* yTrailingPadding = @"";
           if (isFirstView && topPadding > 0) {
               yLeadingPaddingString = @"-topPadding-";
           }
           else if (!isFirstView && verticalPadding > 0) {
               yLeadingPaddingString = @"-verticalPadding-";
           }

           if (isLastView && bottomPadding > 0) {
               yTrailingPadding = @"-bottomPadding-";
           }

           [verticalConstraint appendFormat:@"%@[%@%@]%@",
               yLeadingPaddingString,
               viewName,
               height > 0 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%f)", height] : @"",
               yTrailingPadding];

           NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:
                   [NSString stringWithFormat: @"H:|-horizontalPadding-[%@%@]%@|",
                   viewName,
                   (width > 0 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%lf)", width] : @""),
                   width > 0 ? @"-" : @"-horizontalPadding-"]
               options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing
               metrics:metrics
               views:bindings];

           // high priority, but not required.
           for (NSLayoutConstraint* constraint in constraints) {
               constraint.priority = 900;
           }

           // Add the horizontal constraint
           [self addConstraints: constraints];
       }

       if (alignment == VerticalAlignBottom || alignment == VerticalAlignStretchToFullHeight) {
           [verticalConstraint appendString:@"|"];
       }

       NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint
               constraintsWithVisualFormat:verticalConstraint
               options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeading
               metrics:metrics
               views:bindings];
       for (NSLayoutConstraint* constraint in constraints) {
           constraint.priority = 900;
       }

       // Add the vertical constraints for all these views.
       [self addConstraints:constraints];
   }
   ```