# updating UIView synchronously with changing array values

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

I want to create multiple horizontal bars in a `UIView` according to the data fetched from an array.
I want something like this :

[image: desired look]

but when I am trying to make it generic, it shows something like this:

[image: undesired look]

Here is my `draw` function:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let currentGraphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    var sumOfAllSegments : CGFloat = 0
    dataToRepresent.forEach {(element) in
        sumOfAllSegments += CGFloat(element["value"] as! CGFloat)
    }
    var lastSegmentRect = CGRect()
    var progressRect = rect
    dataToRepresent.forEach { (element) in
        let currentSegmentValue = element["value"] as! CGFloat
        let color = element ["color"] as! CGColor
        let percentage = (currentSegmentValue/sumOfAllSegments) * frame.width
        progressRect.size.width = percentage
        progressRect.origin.x = lastSegmentRect.origin.x + lastSegmentRect.size.width
        if(progressRect.origin.x > 0) {
            progressRect.origin.x += 2.0
        }
        lastSegmentRect = progressRect
        makingBars(rect: progressRect , color: color , context: currentGraphicsContext)
    }
}
```

and `makingBars` function :

```
    func makingBars(rect : CGRect , color : CGColor , context : CGContext) {
    context.addRect(rect)
    context.setFillColor(color)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            context.fill(rect)
        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT 1:***

Here is the screenshot of the crash :
[image]

***EDIT 2:***

[image]

Comment: You cant use DispatchQueue to draw process.

Comment: Why not trying to set the height for the bars? You are setting the width and it is working, but you are not controlling anything about the heigth. You can calculate it from the y position and height of the top bar and the y position of the bottom bar. `progressRect.size.height = (topBar.origin.y + topbar.size.height) - botttomBar.origin.y`

Answer (score 1):

You are not setting the height of your rects correctly, as pointed out by  Aitor Pagán in his comment.

In addition to that, a view's `draw(_:)` method must operate synchronously. You can't use GCD. Get rid of that DispatchQueue.global()/DispatchQueue.main.async() code. It's preventing your draw method from operating correctly. (The system sets up the drawing context before calling our draw method. The drawing context is no longer valid outside of the draw method, and the way you're using GCD, your fill call doesn't get called until after the draw method has returned.)

Comment: i am setting height for my rects using :
progressRect.size.height = frame.height * 2

and if i am not using GCD,  my app crashes giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS on context.fill(rect) line

Comment: The code you posted does not set `progressRect.size.height` at all. If you've updated your code, edit your question to show the new code. The GCD code you posted is absolutely wrong, and will never work correctly. I'm not sure why you are crashing, but that's the wrong solution. Post your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-layout makes it easier for implementing such type requirements.You can find this thread useful.
[Creating a 3x3 grid with auto layout constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641910/creating-a-3x3-grid-with-auto-layout-constraints)
but in that case you have to make constraint programmatically. Manual frame based layout creates problem because we have different screen size as well as rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/damienlaughton/e41fbf4f4df48a4313e85224e33390d2) is of a custom UIView which draws horizontal blocks, it's a view which draws a battery gauge. It does it just by adding subviews.

I suspect that your code is just mis-calculating some frames - to test this you could change the colour of each bar and/or just draw a small number of bars to check for overlapping frames.

Comment: I think your code is bad. You are using drawRect method not on purpose.

Comment: I dont think I understand you. From the docs "Subclasses that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing code there.". That's what this subclass does... By all means my code may still be [very] bad

Comment: You need to use CoreGraphics functions to implement bitmap representation of the view in this method. But you change view hierarchy  this is wrong. You can do this but this is bad way.

Comment: No, see doc - UIKit is permissible in drawRect. Here is the link - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect

Comment: You can use UIKit like [image drawInRect:], [string drawInRect:] etc. `The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing code there. You do not need to override this method if your view sets its content in other ways. For example, you do not need to override this method if your view just displays a background color or if your view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object.`

Comment: Hey I can do that too - LOOK - "By the time this method is called, UIKit has configured the drawing environment appropriately for your view and you can simply call whatever drawing methods and functions you need to render your content."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139849/discussion-between-sergey-and-damo).

Answer (score 0):

Try change you code by some think like this:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    guard let currentGraphicsContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    var sumOfAllSegments : CGFloat = 0
    dataToRepresent.forEach {(element) in
        sumOfAllSegments += CGFloat(element["value"] as! CGFloat)
    }
    var position: CGFloat = 0
    var progressRect = rect
    dataToRepresent.forEach { (element) in
        let currentSegmentValue = element["value"] as! CGFloat
        let color = element ["color"] as! CGColor
        let percentage = (currentSegmentValue/sumOfAllSegments) * frame.width
        progressRect.size.width = percentage
        progressRect.origin.x = position
        if(progressRect.origin.x > 0) {
            progressRect.origin.x += 2.0
        }

        makingBars(rect: progressRect , color: color , context: currentGraphicsContext)
        position += progressRect.width + 2.0
    }
}
func makingBars(rect : CGRect , color : CGColor , context : CGContext) {
    context.addRect(rect)
    context.setFillColor(color)
    content.drawPath(using:.fill)
}
```

Comment: Do you call draw(rect:) by self? Can you provide call stack in crash?

Comment: no I am not calling draw(rect:) by self , and check EDIT 2 for call stack