# Split UIImage Using swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

```
func cropImage(image: UIImage, tileSize: Int) -> [UIImage]? { 
    let hCount = (image.size.height)/CGFloat(tileSize)
    let wCount = (image.size.width)/CGFloat(tileSize)            
    var tiles:[UIImage] = []

    for i in 0..<tileSize {
        for p in 0..<tileSize {
            let rect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i)*hCount, y: CGFloat(p)*wCount, width: wCount, height: hCount)

            let temp = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: rect)!
            let img = UIImage(cgImage: temp!)
            tiles.append(img)                    
        }
    }
    print(tiles.count)
    return tiles
}
```

and use it

```
let crp = self.cropImage(image: UIImage(named:"1407.JPEG")!, tileSize: 3)
for i in 0..<9 {
    image.append(UIImageView(image: crp?[i]))
}
@IBOutlet var image: [UIImageView]!
```

I can't append this images and I want split this image to images using swift 3

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it's can't show image in imageview

Comment: Your `cropImage` function works rightly. Your code for showing image has some problem.

Comment: How did you add imageview to view?

Comment: yup code showing image has proplem but I dont know use it. When I click button split I add imageview to view

Comment: you will have to add constraints to your imageviews.

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/q/28641910/6536841